# Reading the namelist causes an error "Repeat count too large"

Tags: fortran, mingw

I have a program containing a namelist:

```
implicit none
real,dimension(20)::Rc,Ic
integer::n_cyl,degree=4
namelist /vars/ n_cyl,degree,Rc,Ic
open(1,file='vars.txt')
read(1,nml=vars)  ! line 19
close(1)
! ..............
open(1,file='vars.txt',STATUS='UNKNOWN',RECL=1000)
write(1,nml=vars)
close(1)
end
```

vars.txt:

```
&VARS
 N_CYL=         12,
 DEGREE=          4,
 RC= 0.256000012    , 0.512000024    , 0.768000007    ,  1.02400005    ,  1.27999997    ,
   1.43700004    ,  1.59399998    ,  1.72000003    ,  1.84599996    ,  1.97200000    ,  2.09800005    ,
   2.40289998    , 8*0.00000000      ,
 IC=  1.77999997    ,  1.71000004    ,  1.57000005    ,  1.44000006    ,  1.25000000    ,
   1.01999998    , 0.870000005    , 0.680000007    , 0.540000021    , 0.379999995    , 0.259999990    ,
  0.170000002    , 8*0.00000000      ,
 /
```

It works without problems if compiled with gfortran on Linux, but when compiling with gfortran on MinGW (Win32) and running it throws an error:

```
At line 19 of file elen.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'vars.txt'):
Fortran runtime error: Repeat count too large for namelist object rc
```

Is this a bug, or is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: Consider using another file unit number. For instance, replace 1 by 21 everywhere. Some lower numbers are reserved by the compiler for "standard out", etc.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Same result.

Comment: Did you convert the line endings? There are differences in "carriage returns" between unix and windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in gfortran with using namelist repeat counts. See:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82086